# DOS application to allow remote management of files over serial link

Tags: file-transfer, ms-dos

Harken back to the days of MS-DOS 6.22.

I have an embedded DOS handheld device, and I'm looking for a tool to manage the files stored on it.  I picture an application I can launch on the device that opens COM1 up for commands to get a directory listing, send/receive files via x/y/zmodem, move/delete files, and create/move/delete directories.

A Windows application can then download a recursive file listing and then manage those files (for example, synchronizing with a local directory).

Keep in mind that this is DOS -- 8.3 filenames, 640K of RAM and a 19200bps serial link (yuk!).  I'd prefer something with source in case we need to add additional features (for example, the ability to get a checksum of a file for change detection).

Now that I've written this description, I realize I'm asking for something like LapLink or pcAnywhere.  Norton no longer sells DOS versions of pcAnywhere and [LapLink V](http://www.laplink.com/llv/) for DOS seems pricy at $50.

Are you aware of any similar apps from those good old days?

Answer (score 2):

I've never used it before, but [kermit for dos](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/mskermit.html) might fit the bill- it does remote terminal emulation - which means you can move file internally, and lets you transfer files.

If you're running a modernish version of windows on one end, [kermit 95](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/k95.html) might also be of interest - though its not freeware apparently

EDIT: Apparently the links were to the old kermit site - [this is the current one](http://www.kermitproject.org/)

from the kermit page, features include

> ```
> Connection establishment and maintenance for a wide variety of connection methods (TCP/IP, X.25, LAN, serial port, modem, etc).
> Terminal emulation.
> Error-free file transfer.
> Internet protocols including Telnet, Rlogin, FTP, and HTTP.
> Internet security methods including Kerberos, SSL/TLS, SSH, and SRP.
> Character-set conversion during both terminal emulation and file transfer – a unique feature of Kermit software.
> Numeric and alphanumeric paging.
> Script programming to automate complicated or repetitive tasks.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The old built-in DOS program `interlnk` (and its companion, `intersvr`) should be sufficient. I used to use it to direct connect DOS-based machines over a two-way serial connection for file transfer. It basically allows you to mount a directory on one PC as a drive letter on the client. This should do what you need. I believe, though, that Windows ended native support for this protocol in Windows 98 (or ME), so you either would have to break out a VM, DOS partition, or DOSbox to run it (though I'm not sure if it would work with DOSbox; I haven't tried).

This is the Wikipedia note on it: [Interlnk/Intersvr on List of MS-DOS Commands - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_MS-DOS_commands#InterSvr_.2F_InterLnk)

The help documents associated with these programs in DOS provided enough information for me to be able to set it up and use it back when I was in highschool, before I had the Internet, so if you can get your hands these programs (which should be included in DOS anyway), you should be able to figure out how to get them running.